# Detach row from BindingSource or DataTable, which was deleted independently

Tags: concurrency, strongly-typed-dataset

In winforms app, I created myBindingSource, myTableAdapter etc via designer, by drag-n-dropping datatable to the form. In the form I have buttons Save and Delete. The requirement is 
when Delete button is clicked it should immediately delete a record from database,
not when Save button is clicked. So I added DeleteMyRecord query to MyDataSet via 
designer and use that delete query to do deletion. The problem is deleted 
record is still in myDataSet instance, so I need to detach it from its datatable. 
If I simply do the following:

```
myBindingSource.DeleteCurrent();
```

it will still make myDataSet dirty, so, when I click Save button it will result in  concurrency conflict. What I want is just detach the deleted row, but not affect other changes if there were any, before I deleted that record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Remove method of the DataRowCollection object to accomplish this.
Whether this is a good design is another matter.